# Regex for Backus-Naur Form

Tags: c#, regex, bnf

i'm trying to make a regex to match a string like:

```
 i<A> | n<B> | <C>
```

It needs to return the values:

- ("i", "A")
- ("n", "B")
- ("", "C")

Currently i'm using the following regex:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9]*)\<(.*?)\>
```

but it only matches the first pair ("i", "A").

I can't find a way to fix it.

Comment: So you want to match start of string or `|`? Try `(?<![^|])\s*([A-Za-z0-9]*)<([^>]*)>`. Actually, `([A-Za-z0-9]*)<([^>]*)>` will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the ^ asserts position at start of a line so it will only check the beginning of each line if you remove that i should work
and add a ? for the empty value see example below

```
string pattern = @"([A-Za-z0-9]?)<(.?)>";
string input = @"i<A> | n<B> | <C>";
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
{
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `|` is part of the string and should be matched, you can make use of the [captures property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures?view=net-5.0) with 2 capture groups with the same name.

```
^(?<first>[A-Za-z0-9]*)<(?<second>[^<>]*)>(?:\s+\|\s+(?<first>[A-Za-z0-9]*)<(?<second>[^<>]*)>)+$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?<first>[A-Za-z0-9]*)` Named group `first`, optionally match any of the listed ranges
- `<(?<second>[^<>]*)>` Match `<` then start named group `second` and match any char except `<` and `>` and match `>`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\s+\|\s+(?<first>[A-Za-z0-9]*)<(?<second>[^<>]*)>` Match a `|` between whitespace chars and the same pattern for both named groups
- `)+` Close group and repeat 1+ times
- `$` End of string

See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3cfirst%3e%5bA-Za-z0-9%5d*%29%3c%28%3f%3csecond%3e%5b%5e%3c%3e%5d*%29%3e%28%3f%3a%5cs%2b%5c%7c%5cs%2b%28%3f%3cfirst%3e%5bA-Za-z0-9%5d*%29%3c%28%3f%3csecond%3e%5b%5e%3c%3e%5d*%29%3e%29%2b%24&i=i%3cA%3e+%7c+n%3cB%3e+%7c+%3cC%3e&o=m) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/gPcWM5)

[image]

Then you could for example create Tuples out of the matches to create the pairs.

```
string str = "i<A> | n<B> | <C>";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"^(?<first>[A-Za-z0-9]*)<(?<second>[^<>]*)>(?:\s+\|\s+(?<first>[A-Za-z0-9]*)<(?<second>[^<>]*)>)+$");            

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    match.Groups["first"].Captures
    .Select(c => c.Value)
    .Zip(match.Groups["second"].Captures.Select(c => c.Value), (x, y) => Tuple.Create(x, y))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(t => Console.WriteLine("first: {0}, second: {1}", t.Item1, t.Item2));
}
```

Output

```
first: i, second: A
first: n, second: B
first: , second: C
```